# I can't view all my MySQL table data on HTML

Tags: html, mysql, go

I got all data from MySQL table and I printed it with "log" function but I need to print it on an HTML page. I could print just one column. I want to print all products data. How Can I Do This?

In short: I want to list all products for the shop page, but I can only list one product. (I will add hundreds of products. Currently, there are only 3 products in my table.)

I haven't solved it for 2 days, I will be very glad if you can help. Many thanks...
**Go File**

```
package main

import ( "database/sql" "fmt" "log" "net/http" "text/template"

_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type product struct { ID int Name string Stock int Price float32 }

var products product

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

products = product{
    ID:    products.ID,
    Name:  products.Name,
    Stock: products.Stock,
    Price: products.Price,
}

appointment, _ := template.ParseFiles("ot.html")
appointment.Execute(w, products)
}

func main() { fmt.Println("Go MySQL Tutorial")

sqlType := "mysql"
sqlUsn := "root"
sqlPass := "2582064"
sqlDatabase := "gowdb"

db, err := sql.Open(sqlType, sqlUsn+":"+sqlPass+"@/"+sqlDatabase)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

defer db.Close()

results, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM products")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

for results.Next() {

    err = results.Scan(&products.ID, &products.Stock, &products.Price, &products.Name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println(products.Name)
}

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PRODUCT 1</h1>
    <div>NAME: {{.Name}}</div>
    <div>PRICE: {{.Price}}</div>
    <div>STOCK: {{.Stock}}</div>
    <div>ID: {{.ID}}</div>
    <div>BUY FROM: xxx.com</div>

<h1>PRODUCT 2</h1>
<div>NAME: {{.Name}}</div>
<div>PRICE: {{.Price}}</div>
<div>STOCK: {{.Stock}}</div>
<div>ID: {{.ID}}</div>
<div>BUY FROM: xxx.com</div>

<h1>PRODUCT 3</h1>
<div>NAME: {{.Name}}</div>
<div>PRICE: {{.Price}}</div>
<div>STOCK: {{.Stock}}</div>
<div>ID: {{.ID}}</div>
<div>BUY FROM: xxx.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT ON LOG(thats ok)**

Electron Mask
Filtrop Mask
Aircrop Mask

**OUTPUT ON HTML PAGE**

PRODUCT 1 NAME: Aircrop Mask PRICE: 19 STOCK: 2 ID: 2 BUY FROM: xxx.com

PRODUCT 2 NAME: Aircrop Mask PRICE: 19 STOCK: 2 ID: 2 BUY FROM: xxx.com

PRODUCT 3 NAME: Aircrop Mask PRICE: 19 STOCK: 2 ID: 2 BUY FROM: xxx.com

Comment: You need to store the data coming from database in a slice. then pass that slice to the `.gohtml` file to render.

Comment: for loop you can follow https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/using-go-templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have *fixed* your code but takes this with a grain of salt as I did not test it. Please have in mind as well that several things in your original code are plain wrong. Just to mention one, the handler was grabbing the response from a global variable. That's a recipe for disaster and you need to get "unused" to do that, or it will bring you troubles further down the road.

The best I can say is have this code reviewed by your teachers.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type product struct {
    ID    int
    Name  string
    Stock int
    Price float32
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    appointment, _ := template.ParseFiles("ot.html")
    appointment.Execute(w, GetProducts())
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func GetProducts() []product {
    var out = make([]product, 0, 10)
    sqlType := "mysql"
    sqlUsn := "root"
    sqlPass := "2582064"
    sqlDatabase := "gowdb"

    db, err := sql.Open(sqlType, sqlUsn+":"+sqlPass+"@/"+sqlDatabase)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()

    results, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM products")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for results.Next() {
        var p product
        err = results.Scan(&p.ID, &p.Stock, &p.Price, &p.Name)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        out = append(out, p)
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return out
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ range $i, $e := . }}
        <h1>PRODUCT $i</h1>
        <div>NAME: {{.Name}}</div>
        <div>PRICE: {{.Price}}</div>
        <div>STOCK: {{.Stock}}</div>
        <div>ID: {{.ID}}</div>
        <div>BUY FROM: xxx.com</div>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. you rescued me :),  I wonder why do we put a dot in "range"     "{{ range $i, $e :=    >.<    }}"?

Comment: You need to iterate over the products you get from the DB, additionally, you need to get the index of that product. If this answer worked for you please mark it as correct. @Melisa

Comment: Yes, it worked for me but I am new on stack overflow, I voted but it does not show. maybe next time. sincerely!